# Awk - Optimization on Large Array Size

Tags: awk

I have some simple awk array functions, they perform well for an array size up to about 5 million, at around 7 million the performance nose-dives. I'd like to know what the cause is and any suggestions on how to fix it.

```
function rand_init(l_rseed) { 
"date +%N"|getline l_rseed; 
srand(l_rseed); 
close("date +%N"); 
PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; 
}   

function get_rand(max) { return int(rand()*max); }

function rm_element(l_ind) { 
g_my_arr[l_ind]=g_my_arr[g_my_arr_sz--]; 
}

function get_rand_element(l_ridx,l_ret) { 
l_ridx=get_rand(g_my_arr_sz);
l_ret=g_my_arr[l_ridx]; 
rm_element(l_ridx); 
return l_ret; 
}

BEGIN {
rand_init();
g_start_size=7000001; ## 50000001 is quick
for(i=1;i<g_start_size;i++) { 
 g_my_arr[i]=(i)
}
g_my_arr_sz=length(g_my_arr); 
print "size of array is "(g_my_arr_sz);
print "getting a few random elements ..."
 ## Randomly remove all except last 10 elements.
for (i=1;i<(g_start_size-10);i++) get_rand_element(); 
for (i=1;i<=g_my_arr_sz;i++) print "New Array, Index("(i)"): "(g_my_arr[i]);
print "Size of the array is now: "(g_my_arr_sz)
}
```

Starting with g_start_size=5000001, things go fairly well.

```
size of array is 5000000
getting a few random elements ...
New Array, Index(1): 4306493
New Array, Index(2): 316250
New Array, Index(3): 1305392
New Array, Index(4): 602315
New Array, Index(5): 1204246
New Array, Index(6): 4535772
New Array, Index(7): 3865333
New Array, Index(8): 4837828
New Array, Index(9): 88774
New Array, Index(10): 1718274
Size of the array is now: 10

real    0m22.098s
user    0m21.116s
sys 0m0.758s
```

Moving up to g_start_size=7000001, things turn slow.

```
size of array is 7000000
getting a few random elements ...
New Array, Index(1): 894985
New Array, Index(2): 3431108
New Array, Index(3): 240856
New Array, Index(4): 6897693
New Array, Index(5): 3735959
New Array, Index(6): 934555
New Array, Index(7): 1472357
New Array, Index(8): 3793277
New Array, Index(9): 3326249
New Array, Index(10): 6639585
Size of the array is now: 10

real    4m24.952s
user    0m47.130s
sys 1m20.942s
```

Comment: I would guess you've run out of RAM and are now swapping to disk.

Comment: There's going to be some overhead for each element of the data structure itself

Answer (score 0):

(1) awk has associative arrays, not integer-based arrays.  You might want to consider using an interpreted language that supports integer-based arrays.  For example, since ruby has an awk-like mode, you might want to consider that.

(2) If "ary" is an array, then you may be able to exercise some control over memory usage using "delete ary".

(3) On my Mac, using gawk, your program runs in time roughly proportional to g_start_size (e.g. 11s for 5e6, and 17s for 7e6).

(4) mawk is slightly faster (e.g. 15s for 7e6).

Comment: (5) I think you'll find that using @ind_num_asc does not reduce memory consumption.  I've briefly looked at the code (https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/22117307) and have also measured memory usage for your program.  (6) My remarks were intended to support your hypothesis that the "wall" you ran into is most likely related to memory availability.  That is, if you want to circumvent the wall, I think you'll either need more memory, or to use something in the ruby-to-C part of the spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ruby` or `C` at all :

```
 fgc; ( time ( pvE0 < "${m3supp}" |
```

> ```
> mawk2x 'BEGIN { j2e() 
>         } END { ORS = OFS = _ =""
>
>     print ("\f\r\t", split($_,___,_), "\n\n")>("/dev/stderr")
>
>     print joinSix4(___) }' ) | pvE9 ) | xxh128sum
> ```

```
  in0:  197MiB 0:00:00 [1.47GiB/s] [1.47GiB/s] [============>] 100%            
 out9: 0.00 B 0:00:02 [0.00 B/s] [0.00 B/s] [<=>]

207,390,680

 out9:  197MiB 0:00:14 [13.5MiB/s] [13.5MiB/s] [ <=> ]

( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3supp}" | mawk2x ; )  

13.21s user 1.50s system 99% cpu 14.741 total
63ce96aeff0e29ac3da284bb4965d4eb  stdin
```

I fed a `197 MByte` file to  `awk`, asked it to split an array at the byte level, yielding **207** ***million*** cells, then joined it back together as a single and contiguous string, `197 MB` in size, before outputting …

all of which  took `awk` just shy of `14.75 secs` to finish, end to end, as a single core single execution instance of `awk`, without making calls to external apps and shell utilities, or use performance speed up utilities like `gnu-parallel`